# Suggested Edit changed

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I suggested an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2207357) to this question: [Why am I receiving "check if the declared type is right and if the method exists" when retrieving page properties for sling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798882/why-am-i-receiving-check-if-the-declared-type-is-right-and-if-the-method-exists). I'm sure I only fixed the formatting, and while it is possible I accidentally removed the semicolons, I did not add

```
textColor = property.get("textColor", "")
imageURL = property.get("fileReference", "")
```

Where could that have come from? And why did it get accepted with two rejects and only one accept from Community? (Also how can community accept?)

Comment: I think the user edited that in during the grace period and it was "merged" into yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP edited their post after you started writing your edit but before you saved it.  Their edit was within the 5 minute grace period, so it didn't result in an additional revision in the revision history, but since your edit didn't incorporate what they added, it *appears* from your revision, as if you changed that content.

> And why did it get accepted with two rejects and only one accept from Community?

JoshDM didn't vote on your edit, he clicked <kbd>Improve</kbd> and then checked that the edit was helpful, rather than unhelpful.  When that happens the community votes to accept/deny to ensure that the improved edit is applied immediately.

Comment: You really are the *FGITW* cowboy.

Comment: Ok... Got me worried a bit I was going crazy adding random stuff. Thanks :)

Comment: @mwerschy You can still be going crazy. ;)